# Authentication between microservices in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, microservices

We have built a micro-services project on GAE hosting multiple services on GAE Standard JAVA and Flexible Python environment.
We need to implement authentication for Service-To-Service and Client-To-Service communication.
For **Client-to-Service**, we already have form-based authentication model which authenticates client to service by exchanging domain cookie-based auth token,  generated by service on successful authentication. Now, with a different microservice on GAE, we either need to replicate the auth token generation and validation logic there as well or move this authentication logic to some central Authentication Service itself. 
Our web and android client communicate to our backend services in this fashion.
Now, the need is to establish authentication(and authorization later) for Service-to-Service communication.
I have been reading GAE documentation on Application security to check if it helps to quickly setup such authenticated communication among microservices on GAE. Though there are some security provisions and settings offered by GAE but all looked very limited and no-so-general(riddled with caveats!).Something very quick like use of X-appengine-* headers for inbound-appid etc. would not work with custom domains. Firewall rules and service account settings mainly work at Application level not service level. 
Based on reading so far, It seems, we need to write some dedicated Authentication Service that generates and validates JWT Tokens for communicating parties whether client or services.
We want a very generic and customizable solution which fits to future requirement of SSO login with minimal effort. 
Wondering if anybody already coded to make authenticated and authorized communication among microsservices on GAE(mixed with standard and flexible setups) with custom domain and would be generous to share his/her experience :)

Comment: While you may be using a custom domain for user-facing traffic, you can still use the `.appspot.com` domains for communication between your microservices hosted on GAE. This will allow you to rely on the `X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid` headers and would likely make your task quite a bit easier.

If there are legitimate reasons why you can't do that, perhaps the documentation around [Asserting identity to third-party services](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/appidentity/#asserting_identity_to_third-party_services) will help.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Yes, we can definitely go with '.appspot.com' domain for Service-to-Service communication but given that some microservices are hosted on Flexible GAE environment, this too does not work in the absence of 'X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid' header for the requests issued by microservices from Flex env. Though, the same flex env microservices do recieve 'X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid' header in requests issued by microservices from Standard env. Isn't this crazy on Google's part?

Comment: I wonder, If all micros-services are hosted on one datacenter for a multi-services GAE project then why such communication disparity at app engine level. This is unnecessary making service to service communication, even on GAE, way too complicated than it should be.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure about which data centers they host from or why the Flexible environment doesn't allow use of the URLFetch API and therefore include the restricted header.  That said, you might consider using that same pattern. Set your own custom header, perhaps with your own generated/rotated API key stored as an environment variable and verified by the microservice.  That may be as lightweight as you can get without getting too far outside the norm.

Comment: @erichiggins, Agreed.One thing for sure here is that we are not going to rely any of feature/support from GCP and design our some standard authentication/authorization(based on oAuth/openID connect, JWT tokens signing etc. ) mechanism to get our microservices talking with and without user identity.Indeed, GCP support for such obvious requirement has been a BIG DISAPPOINTMENT. We spent good amount of time to only confirm that GAE application security support is inadequate and insufficient for any practical application hosting.

Comment: I strongly suggest, GCP team should mention these limitations/caveats in their documentation at first place, more frankly.

Comment: I struggled with this as well. What I've done is what you mentioned - write a central Authentication Service that handles / authenticates all requests using the domain cookie. That service can then create a JWT which is then used for service-to-service calls.

Comment: thanks for sharing your experience @yoonjesung